# My code doesn't work on CodePen or JsFiddle when I upload it but works fine in my browser. Would anyone be able to help me please?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle, web-frontend

I am new to codePen. I am probably doing a stupid mistake but would any one be able to point it out please?

`function initialDraw(e) {
  var surfaceContext = surface.getContext('2d');
  surfaceContext.drawImage(wheel, 0, 0);
}`

http://codepen.io/hTeeML/pen/RPJemx

Comment: The JS file is on Dropbox? That could be it. A permissions thing?

Comment: The dropbox permission is open to everyone

Comment: But perhaps there is a Codepen / JSfiddle restriction?

Comment: But then my css wouldn't have worked as well

Comment: Then I don't know what to tell you. I know that injecting outside (unknown source) JS is not terribly secure so perhaps they disabled it.

Comment: Why not post the same question on [**CSS-Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/forums/forum/other-discussions/) which is run by Chris Coyier who designed Codepen and ask him?

Comment: It's definitely related to the way the file is being served from Dropbox. I checked the web console while the CodePen was executing, and the message said that the script couldn't be executed because its mime type was text/html. Unfortunately, I don't know if there's a good way to fix that other than copying the script into the CodePen JS directly.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox doesn't serve the raw js file but a html document displaying the javacript. This is legitimately seen by the browser as wrong and therefore unusable.

See here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbt9dzsepaie0tp/winwheel_1.2.js?dl=0

Output from the firefox console when loading the CodePen page:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' winwheel_1.2.js:1:0

Dropbox file start:

> `<!DOCTYPE html>`

### Sidenote

Your javascript contains occurences of this pattern:

```
var wheelImageName = url("http://i60.tinypic.com/t9f7s1.png");
```

This will not only fail because it is interpreted as a function but also because this is the wrong data format for the `src` attribute of an `img` tag.

Fixed code:

```
var wheelImageName = "http://i60.tinypic.com/t9f7s1.png";
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to look at it. This worked.